# Access SkyDNS etcd API on Google Container Engine to Add Custom Records

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, etcd

I'm running a kubernetes cluster on GKE and I would like to discover and access the etcd API from a service pod. The reason I want to do this is to add keys to the SkyDNS hierarchy.

Is there a way to discover (or create/expose) and interact with the etcd service API endpoint on a GKE cluster from application pods?

We have IoT gateway nodes that connect to our cloud services via an SSL VPN to ease management and comms. When a device connects to the VPN I want to update an entry in SkyDNS with the hostname and VPN IP address of the device.

It doesn't make sense to spin another clustered DNS setup since SkyDNS will work great for this and all of the pods in the cluster are already automatically configured to query it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm running a kubernetes cluster on GKE and I would like to discover and access the etcd API from a service pod. The reason I want to do this is to add keys to the SkyDNS hierarchy.

It sounds like you want direct access to the etcd instance that is backing the DNS service (not the etcd instance that is backing the Kubernetes apiserver, which is separate).

> Is there a way to discover (or create/expose) and interact with the etcd service API endpoint on a GKE cluster from application pods?

The etcd instance for the DNS service is an internal implementation detail for the DNS service and isn't designed to be directly accessed. In fact, it's really just a convenient communication mechanism between the `kube2sky` binary and the `skydns` binary so that `skydns` wouldn't need to understand that it was running in a Kubernetes cluster. I wouldn't recommend attempting to access it directly.

In addition, this etcd instance won't even exist in Kubernetes 1.3 installs, since `skydns` is being replaced by a new DNS binary `kubedns`.

> We have IoT gateway nodes that connect to our cloud services via an SSL VPN to ease management and comms. When a device connects to the VPN I want to update an entry in SkyDNS with the hostname and VPN IP address of the device.

If you create a new service, that will cause the cluster DNS to have a new entry created mapping the service name to the endpoints that back the service. What if you programmatically add a service each time a new IoT device registers rather than trying to configure DNS directly?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize SkyDns used it's own etcd instance but it doesn't seem like it's an impl detail as [the documentation](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns) is rife with etcd curls (or perhaps you meant the specific DNS server used is a detail). Also, isn't kube-dns just a name for the DNS Addon that wraps Sky? I did attempt creating services for the devices, but kubernetes creates a cluster-ip for the service and I could not find a way to convey the VPN IP of the device so that kube2sky would create a proper DNS entry. This is my first k8s experience, excuse my newbeté

Comment: With 1.2 and earlier, cluster DNS was a triplet of `kube2sky`, `etcd`, and `skydns`. Starting with 1.3, cluster DNS is two pieces: `kubedns` and `dnsmasq`. You can create a service without a cluster IP (see http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#headless-services) and you can also manually set endpoints for a service.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Cool to see use of dnsmasq, that's what I was contemplating using if I can't get this to work. I saw the headless service stuff, but the documentation is so light that it didn't look like it would work sans a selector. If I create a selectorless headless service will kubedns register the endpoint IPs?

Comment: Took a look at the [sky2dns code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky/kube2sky.go#L127) and wow, that's exactly how it works! Thank you for taking the time to help me with this! Now just trying to think the best way to coalesce this into helpful info for future searchers. Do you mind if I edit your answer or I can create a new answer (I'd like to give you the accept though)?

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to make it clear. If the documentation is light and you are willing to help fix it (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io), that would probably be even more useful than cleaning up this SO answer. :)